# How to drop straight a cup of water with a ball within it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics

I want to drop a cup of water with a ping pong ball within it so that it falls straight (as much as possible) and that I can reiterate the experiment rigorously...

I've seen someone using magnet and a specific system that sadly I cannot build at home. My idea is to hold the cup and trigger something that let fall the cup with the ping pong ball but nothing good comes in my mind. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks for reading

Comment: Is something wrong with holding it still and letting go?

Comment: Or use some string and cut that?